# Need help reading in 2 digit numbers in a text file

Tags: java

This is my code for the project currently. I have any number 10 or above it reads each individual digit instead of the whole number. Any help?
Numbers I am using:

> 1 3
>
> 1 1
>
> -1 -5
>
> 5 3
>
> 45 45
>
> 1001001100 1001001100

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class comparison_rylan_howard {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new
                File("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Unit1\\comparison.txt"));
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Results.txt")) {

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                double first = reader.nextDouble();
                double second = reader.nextDouble();
                if (first <= -1 || second <= -1) {
                    writer.println("Error");
                }
                if (first > second) {
                    writer.println(">");
                    writer.println(" ");
                }
                if (first < second) {
                    writer.println("<");
                    writer.println(" ");
                } else {
                    writer.println("=");
                    writer.println(" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you need help? What should the program do and how is it failing?

Comment: The program compares two positive numbers to state which one is greater or if the are equal. Everything works fine except it is reading each individual digit, such as 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0 instead of 1001001100.

Comment: I don't think the `first > second` or the negative number cases work properly because you're writing an equals sign or an extra comparison result for those, in addition to `>` or "error". You should have the whole comparison logic within an `if-else if-else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class comparison_rylan_howard {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new
                File("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Unit1\\comparison.txt"));
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Results.txt")) {

            while (reader.hasNext()) {

                double first = reader.nextDouble();
                double second = reader.nextDouble();
                writer.println(first+","+second );
                if (first <= -1 || second <= -1) {
                    writer.println("Error");
                    writer.println("");
                }
                else if (first > second) {
                    writer.println(">");
                    writer.println("");
                }
                else if (first < second) {
                    writer.println("<");
                    writer.println("");
                } else {
                    writer.println("=");
                    writer.println("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0,3.0
<

1.0,1.0
=

-1.0,-5.0
Error

5.0,3.0
>

45.0,45.0
=

1.0010011E9,1.0010011E9
=
```

Comment: What all did you change?

Comment: @RylanHoward Is that the output you wanted

Comment: Yes it is thank you for your help if you could explain what I did wrong so i could learn that would help so much

Comment: @RylanHoward I added writer.println(first+","+second ); so numbers can be seen in output file,you can remove it  if you do not need it and I used if else

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is split each line by the whitespace and then parse each element as an entire Integer. Something like:

```
String[] ints = reader.nextLine().split(' ');
double first = Double.parseDouble(ints[0]);
double second = Double.parseDouble(ints[1]);
```

What that basically does is take the next line, creates an array where each element is split by a space, and then attempts to process the Strings before and after the space as separate doubles.